# Настройка таймера, его обнуление

Tags: javascript, таймер

Не получается реализовать таймер так, чтобы он запускался при нажатии на первую карточку (фактически начало игры) и останавливался, когда все карточки будут перевернуты.
Также нужна функция обнуления таймера.

```js
let Memory = {

  //init function
  init: function(cards){
    this.$game = $(".game");
    this.$modal = $(".modal");
    this.$overlay = $(".modal-overlay");
    this.$restartButton = $("button.restart");
    this.$countMoves = $('.moves')[0];
    this.$infoMessage = $('.info-message');
    this.cardsArray = $.merge(cards, cards);
    this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
    this.setup();
    this.GameTimer();
    this.increaseCounter();
    this.Stars();
    this.stopFunction();
  },

  shuffleCards: function(cardsArray){
  this.$cards = $(this.shuffle(this.cardsArray));
  },

  //start of the game
  setup: function(){
    this.html = this.buildHTML();
    this.$game.html(this.html);
    this.$memoryCards = $(".card");
    this.paused = false;
    this.guess = null;
    this.binding();
  },

  binding: function(){
    this.$memoryCards.on("click", this.cardClicked);
    this.$restartButton.on("click", $.proxy(this.reset, this));
  },

  // when user choose cards
  cardClicked: function(){
    let _ = Memory;
    let $card = $(this);
    //add some classes 
    if(!_.paused && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("matched") && !$card.find(".inside").hasClass("picked")){
      $card.find(".inside").addClass("picked");
      if(!_.guess){
        _.guess = $(this).attr("data-id");
      } else if(_.guess == $(this).attr("data-id") && !$(this).hasClass("picked")){
        $(".picked").addClass("matched");
        _.guess = null;
      } else {
        _.guess = null;
        _.paused = true;
        // Time when cards close
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".picked").removeClass("picked");
          Memory.paused = false;
        }, 600);
        }
        if($(".matched").length == $(".card").length){
          _.win();
        }
    }
  },

  win: function(){
    this.paused = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      Memory.showModal();
      Memory.$game.fadeOut();
    }, 1000);
  },

  showModal: function(){
    this.$overlay.show();
    this.$modal.fadeIn("slow");
    // Congratulation message
    $('.info-message').text('You have won the game with '+numStar+' star. Congratulations!');
  },

  hideModal: function(){
    this.$overlay.hide();
    this.$modal.hide();
  },

  reset: function(){
    this.hideModal();
    this.shuffleCards(this.cardsArray);
    this.setup();
    this.$game.show("slow");
    this.stopFunction();
    this.GameTimer();
  },

  //@description: shuffle function 

  shuffle: function(array){
    let counter = array.length, temp, index;
     // While there are elements in the array
     while (counter > 0) {
      // Pick a random index
      index = Math.floor(Math.random() * counter);
      // Decrease counter by 1
      counter--;
      // And swap the last element with it
      temp = array[counter];
      array[counter] = array[index];
      array[index] = temp;
     }
      return array;
  },

  /*
  * @description make a crid for the cards    
  */
  buildHTML: function(){
    let frag = '';
    this.$cards.each(function(k, v){
      frag += '<div class="card" data-id="'+ v.id +'"><div class="inside">\
      <div class="front"><img src="'+ v.img +'"\
      alt="'+ v.name +'" /></div>\
      <div class="back"></div></div>\
      </div>';
    });
    return frag;
  },

  increaseCounter: function(){
    counter += 1;
    $('.moves').text(counter);
    // Decrease the star according to the number of moves that player made.
    if(counter === 5){
      $('#third-star').css('color','#fefefe');
      numStar = 3;
    } else if(counter === 10){
      $('#second-star').css('color','#fefefe');
      numStar = 2;
    } else if(counter === 15){
      $('#first-star').css('color','#fefefe');
      numStar = 1;
    }
  },

  /*
  * @description calculate time taken to complete a game
  */
  GameTimer: function() {
    const game_start_time = new Date().getTime(); //get the current time when user clicked the first card

    timer = setInterval(function(){

    let current_time = new Date().getTime();
    let current_time_played = current_time - game_start_time; // calculate time elapsed
    let hrs = Math.floor((current_time_played % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let mins = Math.floor((current_time_played % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let secs = Math.floor((current_time_played % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    time_value = hrs + ' hours ' + mins + ' mins ' + secs + ' secs '; // this is to display in the stats modal

    if (secs < 10) {
      secs = '0' + secs;
    }

    current_time_played = mins + ':' + secs;
    $('.timer-played').text(current_time_played);
  }, 500);
  },

    stopFunction: function() {
    clearInterval(GameTimer());
  }
};

  let numStar = 3;
  let counter = 0;
  let cards = [
    {
      name: "php",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/php-logo_1.png",
      id: 1,
    },
    {
      name: "css3",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/css3-logo.png",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      name: "html5",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/html5-logo.png",
      id: 3
    },
    {
      name: "jquery",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/jquery-logo.png",
      id: 4
    }, 
    {
      name: "javascript",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/js-logo.png",
      id: 5
    },
    {
      name: "node",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/nodejs-logo.png",
      id: 6
    },
    {
      name: "rails",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/rails-logo.png",
      id: 7
    },
    {
      name: "sass",
      img: "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/74196/sass-logo.png",
      id: 8
    },

  ];
    
  Memory.init(cards);
```

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: url('http://dreempics.com/uploads/posts/2016-06/1466216313_7.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3em;
}

.game {
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-perspective: 500px;
          perspective: 500px;
  width: 660px;
  min-height: 680px;
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, #02ccba 0%, #aa7ecd 100%);
  padding: 32px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 12px 15px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 3em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes matchAnim {
  0% {
    background: #bcffcc;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
  }
}

@keyframes matchAnim {
  0% {
    background: #bcffcc;
  }
  100% {
    background: white;
  }
}


.card {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  background: #87CEEB;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 20px 0 rgba(46, 61, 73, 0.5)
}

.card .inside {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
          transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  transition: .4s ease-in-out;
  background: white;
}
.card .inside.picked, .card .inside.matched {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
          transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .inside.matched {
  -webkit-animation: 1s matchAnim ease-in-out;
          animation: 1s matchAnim ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-delay: .4s;
          animation-delay: .4s;
}
.card .front, .card .back {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
          backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.card .front img, .card .back img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.card .front {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .card .front {
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
.card .back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0);
          transform: rotateX(0);
  background-color: #2F4F4F;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .card .back {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
}

.timer {
 width: 10em;
 margin: 1em;
 text-align: center;
}

.timer-played {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.75em;
}

.steps {
 float: left;
 width: 35%;
}

.score {
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: white;
  width: 6em;
  float: left;
  height: 2.2em;
}

.stars {
  width: 4.5em;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.3em .5em;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  height: 2.2em;
}

.checked {
  color: orange;
}


.restart {
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  padding: 0.3em 1em;
  display: block;
  height: 3em;
  width: 6em;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: #87CEFA;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#87CEFA), to( #4682B4));
  background: linear-gradient(#87CEFA, #4682B4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0 black;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
}
.modal .restart:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#222), to(black));
  background: linear-gradient(#222, black);
}


h2 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}


footer {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.modal-overlay {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
  min-height: 380px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #4682B4;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

.modal > .restart {
  float: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 45%;
}

.modal .winner {

  font-size: 2.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Anton", sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 3px 0 black;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  background: #4682B4;
}

.info-message{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 2em;
}

/*MEDIA QUERIES*/

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .game {
    width: 400px;
    min-height: 450px;
  }

  .card {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
  }

  .score-panel {
    width: 400px;
  }

  .modal .winner {
    font-size: 60px;
  }
}



@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .game {
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
  }

  .card {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }

  h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
  }

  .score-panel {
    width: 300px;
  }

  .score,
  .restart {
    width: 80px;
    font-size: .75em;
  }

  .modal .winner {
    font-size: 40px;
  }

  .modal > .restart {
    width: 150px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Memory Game</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton'>-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="wrap">
    <header>
      <h1>Matching game</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="score-panel">

      <div class="timer">
        <span class="timer-played"></span>
      </div>

      <div class="steps">
        <div class="stars">
          <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="first-star"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="second-star"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked" id="third-star"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="score">
          <span class="moves">0</span> Moves
        </div> 
      </div>

      <button class="restart">Restart</button>

    </section>

    <div class="game"></div>
      <div class="modal-overlay">
        <div class="modal">
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="winner">You are the winner!</h2>
          <button class="restart">Could you play again?</button>
          <p class="info-message"></p> <!--That's for after game info-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Wrap -->
    
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="game.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```